# Is there a way to change color of only Vue directives in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, theming

I am just looking for a way to change color of only Vue directives in Visual Studio Code.

[image: Demo image]

Is it possible with theming VSCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight)

Add this to your `settings.json`

```json
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "( v-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(=)(\".+?\")": {
      "regexFlags": "g",
      "filterLanguageRegex": "html",
      "decorations": [
        { "color": "yellow" },
        { "color": "white" },
        { "color": "green" }
      ]
    }
  }
```

You have to change the colors for your theme.

You can change the regex after the `v-` to include other characters if needed.

Comment: This will highlight rest of the line if there's no value with ="VALUE". for example if i use `v-slot:body`. How can i fix this? Thanks [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/wBu2N1y.png)

Comment: @MalindaWeerasinghe I have changed the character set to include only a-z and numbers

Comment: Thanks buddy. Well I had to modify that a bit to support for directives without a value like `v-slot:body`. This is it `( v-[a-zA-Z0-9:]+)((=)(\".+?\"))?`